# Cast NTEXT to INT for calculation and comparison

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to convert an `NTEXT` column to an `INT` so I can perform some checks on it.

The first check would be is `value = 0`, and the second would be if it was an even or an odd number.  I've got this mostly figured out except the conversion of the `NTEXT` to `INT`. So far what I have is this:

```
cast((cast(a.[Value1] as nvarchar(max))) as int) = 0
```

The column data looks like this `'0'`.  When I run my query I get:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ''0'' to data type int.
```

What are my options to get around this; is there a way to make it ignore the quotation marks?

Comment: Why are you storing integers as `ntext`? Wholly inappropriate datatype. `ntext` is (a) deprecated (b) Was intended for large strings > 8KB (c) is double byte as it is for storing strings containing more exotic characters than just numbers.

Answer (score 1):

See comment by Martin Smith and https://stackoverflow.com/q/2133946/327165 for overview of why not to use ntext.

In order to get numeric records only, including records with numbers that have quotation marks try this: `SELECT REPLACE(CAST(TextValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'''','') FROM Table a WHERE ISNUMERIC(CAST(a.[Value1] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) = 1`

Answer (score 1):

This may be overkill for your need, but you may want a parse-to-integer function which gracefully handles different formats, text values, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (A NTEXT)
INSERT INTO #Test (A) VALUES ('123'), ('ABC'), ('456')
SELECT A, dbo.ParseInteger(A) AS Parsed FROM #Test
```

Output:

```
A   Parsed
123 123
ABC NULL
456 456
```

Here's the UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ParseInteger(@Input VARCHAR(30)) RETURNS BIGINT
AS BEGIN
    IF ISNUMERIC(@Input) = 0 RETURN NULL
    IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@Input)) IN ('.', '+', '-', ',') RETURN NULL
    SET @Input = REPLACE(@Input, ',', '')
    RETURN ROUND(CAST(@Input AS REAL), 0)
END
```

The `NTEXT` column is automatically cast to `VARCHAR(30)`; just about any text value should be fine.  It's not perfectly robust; an input of thirty spaces followed by "123" will *not* parse, for example.